# Tire sidewall tear. Suggestions please?

Tags: sidewall

[image: Picture 3][image: Picture2][Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vynL8.jpg)I hit the curb a couple of days back and damaged my tire and rim. The rim is just scratched. The tire sidewall has tears. There seems to be no air leakage. Took it to a tire service center and the guy said it's fin e and I don't need to change it. I am not sure what to do. The car is ne w with only 2000 miles on it so if I do replace the tire, maybe I can replace only the damaged ones. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the tire guy, the damage isn't bad enough to warrant replacement as it doesn't go deep enough to damage the sidewall. You can cut those pieces off or glue them down (gluing usually looks better) without causing any issues. Keep an eye on those areas of the tire, if you see any bulges in the damaged areas (or anywhere else) get the tire replaced.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep an eye on those areas of the tire.